# Asynchronous data append to file in ios?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, file, save

I'd like to download images from a network path. But since there is a risk of big files,
I thought it would be a good idea to write/append partial NSdata chunks directly to a file in documents directory.
Is this posible?
I have an asynchronous URLConnection set up. 
It calls back to a delegate

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

method.
In this method, I'd like to append the so-far-downloaded "data" to a file directly to the disk.
Can you help a bit?
If this would be posibble without low level C, it would be perfect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I havent tried this ever, but from [this apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html), I'd suggest

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSFileHandle *handle;


//somewhere in a init or viewDidLoad
self.handle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:filePath]

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
   didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [handle seekToEndOfFile];
    [handle writeData:data];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{ 
    [self.handle closeFile]; 
}
```

Note: the filePath must be a valid path for an existing file, there are numerous posts dealing with creating a file.

Comment: The suggestion worked, thanks. The only thing I would add that it is no correct to put the [handle closeFile] in that method. Because on the next call, it would not be possible to append the next chunk of data since the file would be closed (from previous call).
for this ,the -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
 [self.handle closeFile];
} is useful.